# Deny permissions to resouces outside of a users own OU

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am fairly new to Active Directory and this may be a simple thing to do but I am unsure of how to do it.

I have a Organizational Unit in my AD named `WI`, in that OU I have 2 groups `WI Users` and `WI Administrators`, I also have a few users and two RD Session Host Servers in the OU also. There are also other users and computes in other OUs

Here are the basic rules of what I want to do:

1. Any user in any OU that is a member of `WI Users` group is allowed to log remotely in as a standard user to the computers in the `WI` OU.
2. Any user in any OU that is a member of the `WI Administrators` group will be a member of the local `Administrators` group on the computers in the `WI` OU.
3. Any user in the `WI` OU **will not** be allowed to connect to any resource (computer, printer, share, ect.) **outside** of the `WI` OU.

I have figured out how to do everything except rule 3 using AD and Group Policies. What kind of Group Policy do I need to be able to fulfill that third rule?

Currently all I am doing is not adding any users from the `WI` OU to the domain level `Remote Desktop Users` group and adding `WI Users` to the **local** `Remote Desktop Users` for the computers in the `WI` OU. However, what I wrote in rule 3 is my true goal I want to deny network share and printer access too, but I can not just set WI Users as `Deny` in the GPO as people ouside of the `WI` OU will be a member of the `WI Users` group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to remove `'Domain Users'` or `'Authenticated Users'` from each resource you want them to not have access to, and add the OU for groups that you do want to have access to it. Unfortunately, there is not a single method for removing permissions for local log on, share access, and printers.

- Local log on is controlled by `computer config->windows settings->security settings->local policies->user rights assignment` **allow local logon** and **access this computer from the network** and their deny counterparts are the settings that control who can get in.
- Shared printers are controlled from the actual printer share permissions, as are shares, but any computer with the above policy will deny access to these resources if the user is not allowed to access the computer from the network
- There is a way to control share permissions through GPO, but it is not recommended due to performance issues: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Controlling-Resource-Permissions.html